# Justify elements with equal space around them and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to justify 3 images with equal space around them. I set width of images in percents. I tried to use flexbox and `justify-content: space-evenly` but images don't keep aspect ratio:

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpMYoN)

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
</div>
```

I need to keep aspect ratio

Comment: Do note, `space-evenly` won't work cross browsers as not all of them support it. The aspect ratio breaks because of the default `align-items: stretch`, so change it to e.g. `flex-start`. A workaround for `space-evenly` is found in the dupe link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will solve your issue**

I have just added `align-items: center;` to your `.container` and that solves it.

A working sample from your fiddle:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.container img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
</div>
```

Hope this was hlpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `justify-content: space-between;`
If this also not works then you might not be using chrome or latest version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty `<span>` and `space-between` to create equal space around every `<img>`.

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span></span>
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
<span></span>
</div>
```

Or a more grace way which needn't to edit your HTML:

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container::before, .container::after {
    content: "";
}

.container img {
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/status/gtk-missing-image.png" />
</div>
```